# How to get Laravel Eloquent Count and Case in Join

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Good day!

I am having a problem trying a query in my laravel 8 project. In my database, I have 2 tables: users and roles. In users table it has an roles column which is the data inserting in that column is the roles table id.

Or can any one help me to convert this sql command into laravel.

----SQL----

```
SELECT roles.id, roles.role_name, 
    COUNT(users.roles) AS users, 
    roles.permission,
    case when roles.`status` = 1 then 'Active'
    ELSE 'Inactive' 
    END AS `status`
FROM roles
    INNER JOIN users ON roles.id = users.roles 
GROUP BY roles.id
```

--My laravel code that is not working--

```
$data = Roles::select(
        "roles.id",
        "roles.role_name",
        DB::raw("count(users.roles) as users, roles.permission, (CASE WHEN roles.status = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) as status")
    )
    ->join("users", "users.roles","=","roles.id")
    ->groupBy("roles.id")
    ->get();
```

Somebody help me. Thanks

Comment: @ Lawit-wit does my answer helped you?

Comment: Why your Role model is plural ? also what is the exact error it throwing, you may have a problem with your roles model.

Comment: If your model is plural you may have to define the table name is model protected $table = 'roles';

Comment: I already solve my problem sir. By the way there is no problem in my model name, I just find that the exactly error it throws is this `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055`. Thank you so much for the concern sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already know what is cause. First, I can't identify the error because I am using dataTable so the error is from dataTable. Then I tried to fetch the result of my query using view and the error says `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055`

This the solution I deed. Kindly see below:

In `config\database.php`

Find `mysql` array and change the `'strict' => true` to `'strict' => false`

Thank you for help guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DB::table("roles")
->innerJoin("users", function($join){
    $join->on("roles.id", "=", "users.roles");
})
->select("roles.id", "roles.role_name", "count (users.roles) as users", "roles.permission")
->addSelect(DB::raw("case when roles.`status` = 1 then 'active' else 'inactive' end as `status`"))
->groupBy("roles")
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change the model name i.e Role as per whatever your model name is ex: Roles

```
$data = Role::select([
                "roles.id",
                "roles.name",
                DB::raw("count(users.roles) as users, roles.permission, (CASE WHEN roles.status = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END) as status")
            ])
            ->innerJoin("users", function($join){
                $join->on("roles.id", "=", "users.roles");
            })
            ->groupBy("roles.id")
            ->get();
```